# Azure and DNS services

Tags: azure, reverse-dns, dns-zone, azure-networking

I have a `Virtual network` (MyVPN) resource in Azure, being a class C network, MyVPN has `Azure provided DNS service` as DNS servers, so all virtual machines with a NIC connected to this network are able to resolve their hostname successfully, for example virtual machine `myvm01` can ssh to `myvm02` using only the hostname instead of IP.

However, they are unable to make a reverse DNS lookup, which makes sense since by default Azure does not provide a `reverse DNS lookup zone`. [By following Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-reverse-dns-hosting) I managed to create it, sadly I don't really know if I should delegate to `Azure provided DNS service` and if so, how to do it (I tried [following this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns))

What should I do now to allow `myvm01` be able to resolve the IP of `myvm02` to its hostname?

Comment: When following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PTR records created using the document you shared are for internet facing applications, i.e. the DNS zone is accessible from the internet rather than being a private zone in your virtual network.  Right now, Azure doesn't support private DNS zones so it's not possible to create a reverse DNS zones delegation within the Azure-provided DNS resolvers.  To do that you'd need to create a custom DNS server and create the DNS records there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, could you share where this information can be found? (Not supporting DNS zones in private networks)